# Way Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I can not understand where this path is

"Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links"

I want to understand how this piece of code works

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this file under
*Magento_root/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php*
And below code :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links"name="header.links">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>      
   </arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
```

This above code works to add your custom links in the top header section.
If you can see at the bottom of Links.php file there is a function which works to bind the links:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $html = '';
    if ($this->getLinks()) {
        $html = '<ul' . ($this->hasCssClass() ? ' class="' . $this->escapeHtml(
            $this->getCssClass()
        ) . '"' : '') . '>';
        foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
            $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: If this answer helps you. Kindly give me +ve vote.